# C++ To replace GetPixel(), attemping to use bitmap + pointers to speed things up

Tags: c++, winapi

`Getpixel()` is too slow so I am trying to use bitmap to load the RGB values into a pointer to access the RGB values rapidly, but it seems
either I messed up on the bitmap operations or I can't get the pointer right!

I use `Pixelcolor()` to compare so I know I have it right if the returned RGB values matches one another.

Can anyone help me out?

**Here is my code :**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

void cout_colour();
void get_pixel();

void main()
{
   cout_colour();
   get_pixel();
}

void cout_colour()
{
   HDC hdc, hdcTemp;
   RECT rect;
   BYTE* bitPointer;

   int red = 0;
   int green = 0;
   int blue = 0;

   hdc = GetDC(GetDesktopWindow());
   GetWindowRect(GetDesktopWindow(), &rect);

   int MAX_WIDTH = rect.right;
   int MAX_HEIGHT = rect.bottom;

   cout << "MAX_WIDTH" << MAX_WIDTH << endl;
   cout << "MAX_HEIGHT" << MAX_HEIGHT << endl;

   hdcTemp = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);

   BITMAPINFO bitmap;
   bitmap.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(bitmap.bmiHeader);
   bitmap.bmiHeader.biWidth = MAX_WIDTH;
   bitmap.bmiHeader.biHeight = MAX_HEIGHT;
   bitmap.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
   bitmap.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
   bitmap.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
   bitmap.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = 0;   
   bitmap.bmiHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
   bitmap.bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0;


   HBITMAP hBitmap2 = CreateDIBSection(hdcTemp, &bitmap, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void**)(&bitPointer), NULL, NULL);
   SelectObject(hdcTemp, hBitmap2);
   BitBlt(hdcTemp, 0, 0, MAX_WIDTH, MAX_HEIGHT, hdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);


   int i = 1;

   int x = 1;
   int y = 1;
   SetCursorPos(x, y);

   red = (int)bitPointer[i];
   green = (int)bitPointer[i + 1];
   blue = (int)bitPointer[i + 2];

   cout << red << " " << green << " " << blue << endl;

   DeleteDC(hdc);
}

void get_pixel()
{
   int x = 1;
   int y = 1;
   COLORREF hex_color;
   int red;
   int green;
   int blue;
   HDC dc = GetDC(GetDesktopWindow());

   hex_color = GetPixel(dc, x, y);
   red = GetRValue(hex_color);
   green = GetGValue(hex_color);
   blue = GetBValue(hex_color);

   cout << "Super Slow RGB cout!" << endl;
   cout << red << " " << green << " " << blue << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring `bitPointer` as a pointer to an array of `BYTE` values.  You are thus doing 8-bit indexing when getting a pixel from the array.  However, you are creating a 32-bit DIB, which means its pixels are 32-bit, not 8-bit.  You need to declare `bitPointer` as a `RGBQUAD*` instead.

You also need to take the DIB width into account when indexing to a pixel on the 2nd or later line.

You also have to take into account that you are creating a bottom-up DIB instead of a top-down DIB.  That affects how the pixel data is laid out in memory.

`GetPixel()` handles all of these details for you, but since you want to access the pixels directly, you have to do it all manually.

Also, you are not releasing the `HDC` and `HBITMAP` objects correctly.

Try something more like this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

void cout_colour(int x, int y)
{
    HWND hWnd = GetDesktopWindow();
    HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);

    RECT rect;
    GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rect);

    int MAX_WIDTH = rect.right - rect.left;
    int MAX_HEIGHT = rect.bottom - rect.top;

    cout << "MAX_WIDTH " << MAX_WIDTH << " MAX_HEIGHT " << MAX_HEIGHT << endl;

    HDC hdcTemp = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);

    BITMAPINFO bitmap;
    bitmap.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(bitmap.bmiHeader);
    bitmap.bmiHeader.biWidth = MAX_WIDTH;
    bitmap.bmiHeader.biHeight = -MAX_HEIGHT;
    bitmap.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    bitmap.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
    bitmap.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bitmap.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = 0;
    bitmap.bmiHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
    bitmap.bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0;

    LPRGBQUAD bitPointer;
    HBITMAP hBitmap2 = CreateDIBSection(hdcTemp, &bitmap, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void**)&bitPointer, 0, 0);

    HBITMAP hbmpOld = (HBITMAP) SelectObject(hdcTemp, hBitmap2);
    BitBlt(hdcTemp, 0, 0, MAX_WIDTH, MAX_HEIGHT, hdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    LPRGBQUAD hex_color = &bitPointer[(MAX_WIDTH*y)+x];
    int red = hex_color->rgbRed;
    int green = hex_color->rgbGreen;
    int blue = hex_color->rgbBlue;

    cout << red << " " << green << " " << blue << endl;

    SelectObject(hdcTemp, hbmpOld);
    DeleteObject(hBitmap2);
    DeleteDC(hdcTemp);

    ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
}

void get_pixel(int x, int y)
{
    HWND hWnd = GetDesktopWindow();
    HDC hdc = GetDC(wnd);

    COLORREF hex_color = GetPixel(hdc, x, y);
    int red = GetRValue(hex_color);
    int green = GetGValue(hex_color);
    int blue = GetBValue(hex_color);

    cout << "Super Slow RGB cout!" << endl;
    cout << red << " " << green < " " << blue << endl;

    ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
}

int main()
{
    cout_colour(1, 1);
    get_pixel(1, 1);
    return 0;
}
```